# Conditionally change form action in JSP based on combo box selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am have three servers in three different domains. For example,

1. google.com
2. oracle.com
3. sap.com

I have a combo box with the same values as above. How can I change the form action to change to respective site once it is selected in the combo box?

Here is the code i have tried.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"   
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#serverName").on("change",function(){
alert($(this).val());
if($(this).val().toString===("google"))
$("#dataform").attr('action',"http://google.com");
if($(this).val().toString===("oracle"))
$("#dataform").attr("action","http://oracle.com");
if($(this).val().toString===("sap"))
$("#dataform").attr("action","http://sap.com");
});
});
</script>
```

My form is like :

```
<form action="anyaction" name="dataform" method="post" >
<img src="logo.png"><br/>
<label for="email" class="boldtext">Triggered By</label><br>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your mail id" 
required><br/>
<label for="serverName" class="`boldtext`">Server Name</label>
<select id="serverName" name="serverName" >
<option value="selectServer">Select the Server</option>
<option value="google">Google</option>
<option value="oracle" >Oracle</option>
<option value="sap">SAP</option>
</select><br/>
<label for="Clients" name= "Clients" 
class="boldtext">Clients</label><br>
<input type="text" id="count" name="count" 
placeholder="Enter No Of clients" required>
<br/>
<label for="items" name="items" id="items" 
class="boldtext">Items</label>
<textarea id="items" name="items" required rows="3"> </textarea><br/>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: And what happens now when you run it?  Did you view source after changing the combo-box?  Did your alert produce the expected results?

Comment: I was getting the alerts but not the form attribute value. i did not expect the form name to be the spoiler for me "dataform". Once i change the same it works!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some value represented by the name for the form i used "dataform".

Once i change it to dataform123 it worked. also the comparison i have changed from tostring.equals to == / === both of them worked.

Thanks for being there to keep me trying !!